# Flutter local notifications schedule daily starting from the date

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications

Flutter local notifications plugin works fine for daily same-time notifications. But the thing is I need to schedule those notifications starting on a particular date.
this is the code for creating notifications:

```
await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin?.zonedSchedule(
id,
title,
load,
_getNextInstanceOfTime(time),
NotificationDetails(
android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
channelId,
channelName,
notificationDescription,
playSound: true,
styleInformation: DefaultStyleInformation(true, true),
)
),
uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
androidAllowWhileIdle: true
);
```

To everyday schedule:

```
_getNextInstanceOfTime(TimeOfDay time) {
    final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
    tz.TZDateTime scheduled = tz.TZDateTime(tz.local, now.year, now.month, now.day, time.hour, time.minute);
    if(scheduled.isBefore(now)) {
      scheduled = scheduled.add(Duration(days: 1));
    }
    return scheduled;
  }
```

I have a starting date but if I use it instead of now it only shows one notification on that day. Any suggestions would be appreciated.